# parameters in url is automatically deleted in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I built a custom plugin on which I get the value of parameter to validate my page,
Here is my sample code:

```
www.test.com/user/?page="Parameter"

 <?php if(empty($_REQUEST['page'])) { ?>
Landing Page
 <?php }else if( $_REQUEST['page'] == 'add_User'){ ?>
Add User
   <?php }else if( $_REQUEST['page'] == 'edit_User'){
Edit User
<?php } ?>
```

But my problem is wordpress automatically removes the `page="Parameter part"`.

Comment: as far as i remember, you **cannot** use `?page` since it is used by wordpress as well

Comment: here's the list for your perusal https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms just use another one

Comment: $page_id = get_queried_object_id();

Comment: Just replace 'page' to 'pageNumber' or simple 'p' ? Whats a problem?

Comment: 'p' is also a reserved term and it's good to avoid it too

Comment: @Kevin yep it is reserved word thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

`"?page"` is a reserved word that is why it is automatically culled.